# Is there a Performance impact if stored varchar data is less than the defined size limit?

Tags: mysql, varchar

If a column defined with `varchar(20000)` and size of the actual data stored is around 4k-5k, Does it make any difference to MYSQL? As I read from MYSQL documentation, there is no difference in **disk** usage when actual data is less than declared size.

My question is, Will there be any impact in a SELECT query on this column? Could I make my queries faster by declaring the `varchar` closer to the actual size I will store in it?

Comment: Your question is rather vague - what kind of impact are you concerned about?

Comment: Does not seem vague to me.  This exact question has been a curiosity of mine that I've had no chance to create a performance test for.

Answer (score 7):

No. `VARCHAR` strings are stored this way: some bytes are used to store the effective lenght of the string (in your case 2 bytes I think), and then N bytes are used to store the string where N is equal to the lenght of your string.

So, for example, if you store `'example'`, only 9 bytes are used.

There are no impact in `SELECT` query, both for speed and memory usage.